# Looking for prototype for ease-in function

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I'm looking for some kind of ease-in function. Within the range of $0 < x < 1$, $0 < y < 1$ and depending on a parameter $0 < g < 1$ it should have the following properties:
$$ f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1, f'(0) = 0, f'(1) = \infty $$
$$ f(x, g = 0) = x, f(x, g = 1) = 0$$
$$ f\left(\frac{1}{2} + g\right) = \frac12 - g, f'\left(\frac{1}{2} + g\right) = 1$$
So basically it is symmetric about y = 1 - x and crosses that line perpendicularly. I tried to stitch it together from two 3rd degree polynomials, which almos does the job, but not exactly.

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ELRW.png)

Biggest issue is that it becomes negative as the parameter gets larger. I'm not quite sure what to look for, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the equation for a quarter-arc of a square superellipse:
$$x^n+y^n=1$$
The arc is symmetric about $x=y$ and passes it perpendicularly. At $n=1$ it generates a straight line ($g=0$) and as $n\to\infty$ it generates a constant one function ($g=1$). If we now take $n=\frac1{1-g}$ and flip the curve vertically we get an easing curve that satisfies most of the desired properties:
$$y=1-(1-x^{1/(1-g)})^{1-g}$$
It does not satisfy $f'(1)=1$, but if the arc is symmetric then given $f'(0)=0$, $f'(1)$ would have to be $\infty$.

Comment: Amazing, that was exactly, what I was looking for. I thought about a circle but did not investigate further. And yep, f'(1) = inf, I have corrected my question. Thanks again!